# How to optimize the code which stores visited states in a HashSet?

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, hashset

I am writing a solution to some USACO training problem. Unfortunately my implementation is too slow even though I used in my opinion the correct algorithm (correct answers, too slow to accept the solution). Here is the code:

```
public class clocks {

    private static LinkedList<State> queue = new LinkedList<State>();

    private static HashSet<State> set = new HashSet<State>();

    private static PrintWriter out;

    static long cTime = 0;

    private static class State implements Cloneable {
        public int[] clocks;
        public List<Byte> road;

        public State(int[] clocks, List<Byte> road) {
            this.clocks = clocks;
            this.road = road;
        }

        private void makeMove(byte move) {
            int[] currentMoves = moves[move];
            for (int i = 0; i < currentMoves.length; i++) {
                clocks[currentMoves[i]] = (clocks[currentMoves[i]] + 1) % 4;
            }
            road.add(move);
        }

        @Override
        public State clone() {
            int[] clocks = new int[this.clocks.length];
            System.arraycopy(this.clocks, 0, clocks, 0, this.clocks.length);
            List<Byte> road = new ArrayList<Byte>(this.road);
            State newState = new State(clocks, road);
            return newState;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + Arrays.hashCode(clocks);
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            State other = (State) obj;
            if (!Arrays.equals(clocks, other.clocks))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    }

    private static final int[][] moves = new int[][] {
        {0, 1, 3, 4},
        {0, 1, 2},
        {1, 2, 4, 5},
        {0, 3, 6},
        {1, 3, 4, 5, 7},
        {2, 5, 8},
        {3, 4, 6, 7},
        {6, 7, 8},
        {4, 5, 7, 8}
    };

    private static boolean isValid(int[] clocks) {
        for (int i = 0; i < clocks.length; i++) {
            if (clocks[i] != 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static void bfs() {
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            State currentState = queue.pop();
            if (isValid(currentState.clocks)) {
                for (int i = 0; i <= currentState.road.size() - 1; i++) {
                    System.out.print((currentState.road.get(i) + 1));
                    if (i != currentState.road.size() - 1) {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");
                break;
            }
            for (byte i = 0; i < moves.length; i++) {
                State newState = currentState.clone();
                newState.makeMove(i);
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                boolean added = set.add(newState);
                cTime += System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
                if (added) {
                    queue.add(newState);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("clocks.in"));
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("clocks.out")));
        int clocks[] = new int[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(f.readLine());
            int k = i*3;
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                clocks[k + j] = (Integer.valueOf(tokenizer.nextToken()) / 3 ) % 4;
            }
        }
        State state = new State(clocks, new ArrayList<Byte>());
        queue.add(state);
        if (!isValid(clocks)) {
            bfs();
        }
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
        System.out.println(cTime);
        f.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

I noticed that the most time-absorbing is adding new elements to the set (90 / 200 ms) and creating new states (70 / 200 ms). I wonder if it's possible to implement this solution in more efficient way (e.g. without the `State` class).

Problem statement:

> Consider nine clocks arranged in a 3x3 array thusly. The goal is to find a minimal sequence of moves to return all the dials to 12 o'clock. Nine different ways to turn the dials on the clocks are supplied via a table below; each way is called a move. Select for each move a number 1 through 9 which will cause the dials of the affected clocks (see next table) to be turned 90 degrees clockwise.

Comment: You should probably head over to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ since this code already works. It's a lot of code to look trough.

Comment: See one hint in http://acmph.blogspot.mx/2012/12/usaco-clocks.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember this problem correctly, then I had the same issue that you did, in that your solution as written is not actually correct. :)

The key insight here is to realize that pushing a button four times is the same as never having pushed the button, which your code does not implement as it is right now. Since there are nine buttons, and each button has four states, that's 4^9 operations to check, which is well within reasonable bounds. Hopefully without delving too much into detail, you can either incorporate this into your BFS or just use a brute force algorithm.